# Cannot execute powershell file with function call in Transact SQL script

Tags: t-sql, powershell

I have a problem with my Transact SQL script, I made a procedure in Transact SQL which has to execute a powershell script with a function. When I execute the file and method in the Command Prompt it works but if I put the command in Transact SQL it gives me an error saying that it doesn't recognize the command. I hope someone could help me.

Command Prompt command

```
powershell -command "& { . C:\Users\mslaats\Desktop\Databasescripts\Powershell\GmailLibrary.ps1; SendGmail "<email address>" "subject" "body" }"
```

Transact SQL script

```
PRINT 'Use the Divestar database'
USE [Divestar]
GO

PRINT 'Grant access to execute through a kind of cmd'
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

-- Delete the old procedure
PRINT 'Drop procedure'
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS [dbo].[SendEmail]
GO

-- Procedure --
PRINT 'Create procedure to send an email'
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SendEmail]
    @To         VARCHAR(1024),
    @Subject    VARCHAR(1024),
    @Content    VARCHAR(1024)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CMD    VARCHAR(1024)

    SET @CMD = 'powershell -command "& { . "C:\Users\mslaats\Desktop\Databasescripts\Powershell\GmailLibrary.ps1"; SendGmail "<email address>" "onderwerp" "bodytje" }"'
    PRINT @CMD

    EXEC xp_cmdshell @CMD
END
GO
```

Transact SQL script error

```
. : The term 
'C:\Users\mslaats\Desktop\Databasescripts\Powershell\GmailLibrary.ps1' is not 
recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify 
that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:7
+ & { . C:\Users\mslaats\Desktop\Databasescripts\Powershell\GmailLibrary.ps1; 
Send ...
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\mslaat...mailLibrary.p 
   s1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

SendGmail : The term 'SendGmail' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or 
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:77
+ & { . C:\Users\mslaats\Desktop\Databasescripts\Powershell\GmailLibrary.ps1; 
Send ...
+                                                                             
~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SendGmail:String) [], CommandNo 
   tFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

NULL
```

Comment: Is the path valid (C:\Users\mslaats\Desktop\Databasescripts\Powershell) ?

Comment: And what execution policy do you have on the PS session that you open ?

Comment: The path is valid otherwise it would not work in the command prompt

Comment: Both the folder from the T SQL script and the folder with the Powershell script have the "remotesigned" policy

Comment: can you try this (I think this might be a quotes problem) powershell -command '& { . C:\Users\mslaats\Desktop\Databasescripts\Powershell\GmailLibrary.ps1; SendGmail "<email address>" "subject" "body" }'

Comment: T SQL uses the ' character as a varchar, so if i use that character I need an escape character. The thing is that the command works in cmd but not in my script...

Answer (score 0):

After encountering this same problem, I've found out that I needed to check the ExecutionPolicy on both machines. I knew my ExecutionPolicy was fine on my machine, but I checked the SQL server machine via:

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'powershell -command "& { Get-ExecutionPolicy }" '
```

which returned `Restricted` (which means that no Powershell script can run, and hence I ran into the same error message that you did).

Additionally, I also made sure my script was stored in a location that SQL Server had permission to access. You could check this in your case with a command like:

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'powershell -command "& { dir C:\Users\mslaats\Desktop\Databasescripts\Powershell }" '
```

And that command will let you know if SQL can see your script or not. In my case, I put my script in a shared network location I knew SQL could already access.